# How to exempt csrf token in flask application factory

Tags: python-3.x, flask, csrf-token

I am using flask's application factory and I am trying to exempt a route. If I put `csrf.exempt(team_routes.team_bp)` it works, but I only need to exempt the `team_bp.stat` route.  I have tried `csrf.exempt(team_routes.team_bp.team_stats)`

```
csrf = CSRFProtect()

def create_app()
    ....
    csrf.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(team_route.team_bp)
```

my `team_route.py` file

```
 team_bp = Blueprint()

 @team_route.route('/stat/')
 @current_app.csrf.exempt
 def team_stats():
```

When adding `@current_app.csrf.exempt` in the route I get the following error `Flask object has no attribute csrf`.  If I add the `csrf_token()` to the form and submit it works. But I want to have the `stat` route exempt

Comment: Me too!  I am having the same issue converting from simple flask to Factory. It was working fine as @csrf.exempt  with  simple start so there is something up with factory pattern.

Comment: Yes the application factory seems to be the issue.  Haven't found a solution but if I do I will post here.  I just added the token to all.  Not a huge issue but not idea either.